# How to stop a running AHK script whitout closing the script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have written an AHK script that sends a set of keyboard keys when the hotkey `^!e::` is pressed. This script needs a couple of seconds to complete, but sometimes I need to stop the execution before the script has finished doing its task. I know that this can be done by setting the `ExitApp` function to another hotkey, but this will close the script. So, if I need to trigger the script again, it will be necessary to open the `.ahk` file anew.

How could the script be stopped without closing it? I would also need that, when it is triggered again, it sends the keys from the beginning, and not from where it left off when I stopped it.

**Edit:** let's take as an example this code,

```
^!q::
SoundBeep, 208
SoundBeep, 155
SoundBeep, 208
SoundBeep, 196
SoundBeep, 208
return
```

Comment: See [exit](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Exit.htm) and [reload](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Reload.htm).

Comment: @User1234321 How could these functions be applied to the problem? I have looked at their descriptions, but it is not clear to me how they are to be used in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to resolve the issue is to have two different script-files.

**MainScript.ahk:**

```
; Starts the secondary-file into its own process:
^!l::run SecondaryScript.ahk  ; Ctrl+Alt+L
```

**SecondaryScript.ahk:**

```
#SingleInstance Force

SoundBeep, 208
SoundBeep, 155
SoundBeep, 208
SoundBeep, 196
SoundBeep, 208
ExitApp

^!q::ExitApp   ; Ctrl+Alt+Q
```

After the SecondaryScript has finished its auto-executing of code, then it will issue `ExitApp` which will kill the process that the file is currently being executed inside of.

If you want to abort the execution, then you can use the hotkey that is defined under the Auto-Execute portion of the script.

Answer (score 1):

to do that:
1.go to the system tray ([image: wintray])
2.right-click on the [image: autohotkey logo] symbol.
3.click on suspend hotkeys

What happens when you click on pause script? Something horrible.
ex:if you remapped the
[image: a key] key, that useful key will be shutdown.

*hope this helped.*

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick to relaunch current script without a separate launcher script:

```
Esc::
Reload
ExitApp
```

`Reload`, obviously, reloads the current script.
(NOTE: Command-line parameters aren't passed down to the new instance.)
And then `ExitApp` makes sure current instance dies right away and even if the reload fails.

The effect is similar to the solution by Hampus, but doesn't require hardcoding or otherwise specifying any file names within the scripts, and is much more convenient for scripts with multiple long-running hotkeys, which would require a separate script file each with the launcher approach.